# Access My Server From External Net IP While Server is Using PPTP

Tags: ubuntu, web-hosting, pptp

I have one physical Ubuntu server where I'm using PPTP with HMA for tormenting (using Deluge) and hosting the Deluge Web-UI, Ajenti and Ajaxplorer. 
While PPTP is engaged I can access my three web-UIs just fine through my local 192.168.1.0/24 network, but I can't connect to them through my external IP. 
I have port forwarding enabled on my router and I can access everything externally when PPTP is disabled on my Ubuntu box.

Is there a way I can have PPTP running and still be able to connect to my web-UIs from my external network?

If this is a limitation with PPTP, HMA also supports OpenVPN. I'm willing to switch over to OpenVPN is it'll let me run the configuration I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a PPTP problem.  You would have the same problem with any VPN software.  It is a simple routing problem.

You most likely have your default gateway pointed at the VPN, you would have to for it to be of any use for torrent hiding.  If your default gateway is AIMed at the VPN, then routing will not work right.  Short of some advanced policy routing there really no way to make this work.

Policy routing would require that you setup two route tables.  One for your torrenting, and one for your web traffic.  Then you have to setup rules that force particular types of traffic to one of those tables.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I'll investigate policy routing. It would be nice if I could direct all port 22, 80 & 4433 traffic through one gateway and then send everything e3lse through PPTP.